# How do I set random numbers that fall in a range in kdb+?

Tags: kdb

In Kdb+, how do I use the "roll" function to make the random numbers generated fall within a range that doesn't start with 0? For example what if I wanted the range to be within 2-10 instead of 0-10?

What do I have to add to the code to make it fall into a range instead of the default 0-x? I have tried and looked for every method but can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 5):

You could also just roll from 0-8 then add two. This doesn't require a list to be pre-generated

```
q)2+5?9
10 2 7 10 7
```

Assuming you want 2-10 inclusive

Answer (score 0):

```
// quick and simple method
q)10?2+til 8
6 2 4 3 4 3 4 5 4 7
// or function (x)=num to be dealt, (y) start range, (z) end range
q)f:{x?y+til 1+z-y}
q)f[10;10;20]
12 17 10 11 19 12 11 18 18 11
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to that code, not a link to some external documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you supply a list in the right hand argument then you will get a random value from that list. To roll for a random range from 2-10 you can use `til` to generate the range:

```
q)2+til 9
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
q)1?2+til 9
,6
```

You can even supply a general list to randomly draw from:

```
q)3?(`abc;2 3f;10;20;30;"text")
2 3f
`abc
"text"
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was this but I kept putting in 2 til 10. i didn't know you needed the plus sign.

Comment: Note that for big ranges this will create a big list which will take both memory and time.

Answer (score -1):

Simple math function for random number generator is:

(rand() mod (1+max- min)) + min

```
q) f:{x+rand[0] mod  1+y-x}
q) f[5;10]
q) 7
```

**Update:** I failed to notice that you wanted to generate couple of random numbers in the range. You could easily modify above function for that:

```
q) f:{x+(z?0) mod  1+y-x}
q) f[2;10;4]
q) 6 4 7 2
```

Comment: Whoever has given the downvote, its always good to leave the reason for that in comment as that would help everyone to understand the issue.